# События закрытия окна и завершения приложения в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

В старом добром WPF был ряд событий, которые отвечали за закрытие окна. В т.ч. главного окна программы. Но, в UWP аналогичных событий у страницы (Page) нет. Как быть?

К сожалению, гугл не помог.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20346746/how-to-use-application-exit-event-in-wpf

Comment: @Gardes, там решение для WPF, которое на работает под UWP. Хотя реальное решение вопроса я нашел в том же файле App.xaml.cs. Подробнее напишу в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Гугл показал что в UWP нету такого события в принципе.

Вот здесь на эту тему отвечал один из девов майкрсофта: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685285/override-close-box-on-windows-10-universal-apps-uwp

Написав:

> However, with the Creators Update (and corresponding SDK) we have included a preview API that you can now check out for this functionality:
>
> The Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview class provides a CloseRequested event that an app can mark as handled. For the event to work the app will need to declare the restricted 'confirmAppClose' capability per: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

То есть недавно добавили API через который можно реализовать это. Класc `Windows.UI.Core.Preview.SystemNavigationManagerPreview` имеет ивент `CloseRequested` которым можно воспользоватся как тебе нужно.

Деталей реализации не подскажу т.к. сам с UWP не работал, но, думаю, это будет не лищним знать :) Но, куда копать тебе теперь будет ясно :)

---

Использованные кейворды для гугления: "uwp page close event"

Answer (score 0):

У UWP приложения есть ряд событий жизненного цикла. Все они обрабатываются в файле `App.xaml.cs` в корне проекта.

Все эти методы уже изначально реализованы в шаблоне Visual Studio. Но, мы можем их дополнить.

Применительно к данной задаче нужно дополнить метод `OnSuspending`, как показано ниже:

```
private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
    //TODO: Сохранить состояние приложения и остановить все фоновые операции
    /*
    Сюда пишем требуемый код.
    */
    deferral.Complete();
}
```